# How to set application icon in a Qt-based project?

Tags: c++, qt

How do you set application icon for application made using Qt? Is there some easy way? It's a qmake-based project.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

For **Qt 5**, this process is automated by qmake. Just add the following to the project file:

```
win32:RC_ICONS += your_icon.ico
```

The automated resource file generation also uses the values of the following qmake variables: `VERSION, QMAKE_TARGET_COMPANY, QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION, QMAKE_TARGET_COPYRIGHT, QMAKE_TARGET_PRODUCT, RC_LANG, RC_CODEPAGE`.

For **Qt 4**, you need to do it manually. On Windows, you need to create a .rc file and add it to your project (.pro). The RC file should look like this:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "path_to_you_icon.ico"
```

The .pro entry should also be win32 specific, e.g.:

```
win32:RC_FILE += MyApplication.rc
```

Comment: To be safe you should use `win32:RC_FILE += MyApplication.rc`

Comment: how to do it in unity? the standard documentation is insufficient and nothing is found in my ubuntu 12.04 as gnome-config.

Comment: While this sets the icon for the installer (`.exe` file) as well as the desktop app, the uninstaller window which guides the user through the uninstallation process step by step still shows the default icon on the top left. Any idea on how to show the icon there as well? Also, in the Uninstall directory from Control Panel, all apps show their own icons, my app still shows the default exe icon..

Comment: why isnt there a cross platform solution for this. i want the same icon also to be shown on debian executables (also mac?).

Comment: @dwj what do you mean by "safe" ?

Comment: @Suda.nese if you were to define `win32:RC_ICONS` somewhere else in your project file and then simply use `win32:RC_ICONS = x.ico` here, you'd overwrite the previous definition of that variable.

Comment: How to do this on Linux Mint?

Comment: How to do this on Linux/RHEL6 ?

Comment: What if I want to use the same icon, from the RC file, as my form's icon?

Comment: I don't know why but in my environment with 5.6 it does't work, so here is an alternative procedure: 0) convert the image to .ico format using gimp or your favourite graphics program. 1) add RC_FILE = app.rc to the app.pro file 2) create a file named app.rc with one line: IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "app.ico" 3) clean/remove makefiles 4) build the app, 5) Profit.

Comment: This is applied for window app. How about Linux?

Comment: Is `your_icon.ico` just a path to an `ico` file anywhere on the system?

Comment: I have a situation with Qt5 on Windows 10 where I can set the top level window icon correctly. But sub-windows created within the application still have the default Qt icon, even when I specify the parent as the top level window. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23):

Verified in Linux (Qt 4.8.6) and Windows (Qt 5.6):

1) Add the icon file to your project folder;

2) In the main function call setWindowIcon() method. For example:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./images/icon.png"));
```

Comment: This is the icon for the window, when it is opened (the icon on the title bar, for example). The OP wants the icon to see when you use file manager, for example, and you click with mouse to open the program.

Answer (score 3):

To extend Rob's answer, you can set an application icon for macOS by adding and modifying the following line onto your `.pro` file.

```
macx: ICON = <app_icon>.icns
```

Note that the [`ICON` qmake variable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#icon) is only meant to target macOS.

For Windows, use

- `RC_ICONS = <app_icon>.ico` if you're attaching a `.ico` file
- **or** `RC_FILE = <app_icon>.rc` if you want to attach your icon through a `.rc` file. (Be sure to add `IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "myappico.ico"` into the rc file. Indentation not mine.)

For further reading, see [Setting the Application Icon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html).

Answer (score 2):

For Qt5 on Windows, move your ico file to project folder and add this line to your .pro file:

```
RC_ICONS = myappico.ico
```

Offical link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html

Answer (score -2):

Now that Qt has upgraded to 5.0.1, there is new method to add an application icon. First, you need prepare a resource file, named as `.qrc`

1) Without `Qt Designer`, I assume there is a `QMainWindow` instance whose name is `MainWin`. You can use:

```
QIcon icon(":icon/app.icon"); 
MainWin.setWindowIcon(icon);
```

2) With `Qt Designer`, you can modify the property of `QMainWindow`. Choose icon resource from `.qrc` and insert it into the row of `windowIcon`.

The above method can be used in Qt4.7, Qt4.8.x.

Comment: You are wrong. Your method is for setting the form's icon. Not application icon.

Comment: This does NOT answer the OP's question