# Qt Creator - how to set application icon for ubuntu linux?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I have seen the original question [qt-creator-how-to-set-application-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460361/qt-creator-how-to-set-application-icon)

but it did not help me because i am building an app in **ubuntu** and the [Qt`s Documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/appicon.html)
is not clear for me..

Is there anynone, who has done it?
Whats the method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Qt doc link you have specified gives the details for KDE and GNOME. What desktop environment are you running?

Comment: @yasouser: These days all major Linux desktop environments understand the same freedesktop.org specification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux does not have any standard for reading embedded resources, so there is no way to embed the icon in the application binary itself and have it display in the menu and launcher. You will have to install your icon in the appropriate `pixmaps` directory and a `.desktop` file in appropriate `apps` directory pointing to your application and respective icon.

The Qt documentation you quoted refers to [icon theme specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/Standards/icon-theme-spec), which describes where the files should be installed. Look for the *Installing Application Icons* towards the end for summary of what needs to be done.

You will have to install the files in the "install" target of your build system (qmake or cmake or what you use) and possibly create a Debian package on top of that. The Qt Creator is unlikely to help you with these.