# How do I give a C++ program an icon?

Tags: c++, icons, g++

How do I give my C++ program an icon? I'm compiling using g++ on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Linux, executables don't have icons. You need to create a `.desktop` file which you can give an icon. See [here](http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/) for example.

On Windows, you can use resource files to give the files themselves an icon. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) and especially [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381018%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for an explanation.

Comment: Hate to use necromancy, but the gnome-terminal icon is in fact set on the C level.

Comment: @Kookerus I do believe a `.desktop` file can be used to override that (at least so that the `.desktop` file's icon specification takes precedence visually).

Comment: Would that override the default icon in the gnome-panel?

Comment: Depends on the program displaying the icon, obviously. I have no idea where desktop environments or associated programs get their window icons...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what rubenvb and Joe McGrath have already said, note that with Windows, the icon you want to show up as the application's default icon must occur first (i.e. before any other icons) in the resource file.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can include the icon in the executable yourself. There are programs that add resources to the file.  It is not the compiler that adds the resources.

On Linux it is not done in the executable itself.  Was answered previously at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328383/qt-creator-how-to-set-application-icon-for-ubuntu-linux)