# How to set/change the application icon?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm Confused about set the application icon.
I have seen many explanations about set the application icon, but I'm still not understand.
Please I want a simple explanation, but step by step to understand it

**What I have done:**
I have created a Qt `resource file(.qrc)`.
Then, I have added a prefix, then I have added the Icon file.
Then, from design mode and from property block I have changed the a property called `windowIcon`.
Then I have selected the Icon which I added before in the `.qrc` file.

**Notice:** I'm use Qt5.3 and windows 7.

Now, **Please what is the right steps to set the application icon ?**

Comment: You have done the right steps to set the form icon. Do you want to set an icon for the application executable file?

Comment: I want to set Icon to appear in `Taskbar` and in `top left of window` and also `executable file` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set application icon in a Qt-based project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460361/how-to-set-application-icon-in-a-qt-based-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have done the right thing to set the main window icon. Just setting `windowIcon` property in the designer will set an icon for the application window.

For setting an icon to the application executable file there is an automated process In Qt 5.

You can just add the following to the .pro file:

```
win32: RC_ICONS = myIcon.ico
```

Also store the .ico file in your application's source code directory.

Note that this is only for Windows. There are other ways to set application icon in Linux and Mac.

Comment: What is the meaning of this code `win32: RC_ICONS = myIcon.ico`

Comment: `win32:` means this part is only for Windows and has no effect in other operating systems. `RC_ICONS` is a variable containing the application icon file name.

Comment: Why we don't use `setWindowIcon` method for this purpose ?

Comment: Setting the application executable file icon is a process which is done in compile time. `setWindowIcon` takes place at run time. You can not change the executable icon at run time.