# Qt missing application's icon in Windows' bottom bar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Welcome, I have a question about Qt's windows operations. I have a simple app which contains 2 windows:

1. MainWindow - includes push button, can't be resizeable,
2. AdminWindow - includes label, can be resizeable.

When I click push button, it should open AdminWindow and hide MainWindow. I made the app and it seems to work but when I open the AdminWindow, the application icon which is located in windows's bottom bar is missing. How can I fix it?

Icon is showed when MainWindow is opened:
[image]

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "adminwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButtonOpenAdmin_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    AdminWindow *adminWindow;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

// hides MainWindow and show AdminWindow
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonOpenAdmin_clicked()
{
    hide();
    adminWindow = new AdminWindow(this);
    adminWindow->show();
}
```

adminwindow.h

```
#ifndef ADMINWINDOW_H
#define ADMINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class AdminWindow;
}

class AdminWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AdminWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AdminWindow();

private:
    Ui::AdminWindow *ui;
};

#endif // ADMINWINDOW_H
```

adminwindow.cpp

```
#include "adminwindow.h"
#include "ui_adminwindow.h"

AdminWindow::AdminWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AdminWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

AdminWindow::~AdminWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226597/how-to-set-change-the-application-icon

Comment: The icon itself isn't in bottom bar, it looks like I don't open app but app is opened.

Comment: Can i explain it better?

Comment: Yes, check these images how it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/JTpwaxF.png and http://i.imgur.com/RJl6OF5.png

Comment: Think about using `showMinimized()` and `showNormal()` instead of `hide()`.

Comment: But what if I want to completely "hide" MainWindow, because with these methods MainWindow is still showed.