# How to set executable (application) icon in Linux based Qt

Tags: linux, qt, icons, executable

I[image: default icon of executable in linux]
I want to change this default icon to my desired icon. How to do this ?
I have searched and found solution for Windows [How to set application icon in a Qt-based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460361/how-to-set-application-icon-in-a-qt-based-project) but not for Linux.

I have tried to do this using .desktop file by setting
    Icon = myPath/icon.icon or icon.PNG 
But it does not work. Any idea of how to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question isn't really Qt related.

In Linux, icons are set in the .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/` and not on the executable itself. To have an icon for your app, it must be installed on your system. Place the executable in `/usr/bin`, your icon of choice in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/` and put a .desktop file that corresponds to your application in `/usr/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=(insert name of app)
GenericName=("Web Browser", "Media Player", etc. This isn't technically needed but makes your app look native on KDE)
Exec=(insert executable name)
Icon=(insert icon name)
```

Comment: Will the icon remain as it is if i install this application on another Linux system ?

Comment: @AnuragSingh As long as you put the files in the correct places on the other system, then yes, the icon should remain. The easiest way to make sure it works on other systems is to create a package for that system. On Arch Linux, write a PKGBUILD.

Comment: Can we do this by programming ?

Comment: @AnuragSingh No, not on Linux. The same applies for all applications on Linux. :)

Comment: @AnuragSingh Also, regarding your edit, the icon doesn't need a path; it needs a name. Generally it's the name of the icon file that you put in ```/use/share/icons``` without the extension. :)