# Set .exe icon for Qt windows app without qmake/VS

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

**What are the steps to add Qt application icon on windows that shows on exe file in explorer?**

Currently my icons show on app GUI windows but not on the exe file itself in the explorer.

The answer to [How to set application icon in a Qt-based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460361/how-to-set-application-icon-in-a-qt-based-project/38660581#38660581) shows how to do it via qmake, by adding `RC_ICONS` I don't use qmake. I don't use `VS`, I use `VS` compiler and any tools directly, in standard C++ app with Qt.

Is it possible to find steps to do it manually? Qt refers to `winres.exe` but is there a way to use Qt tools directly, or any tools that comes with `VS`?

I add icons manually by compiling them in, I design GUI in Qt Designer then compile via simple batch file on Windows 10. The `dtresources.qrc` is created in Qt Designer. GUI window icons are then selected from resources file.

Example:

```
%qtdir%\bin\rcc -name icons dtresources.qrc -o detail/dtresources.cpp
set src=detail/dtresources.cpp *.cpp

cl /EHsc /MDd /Zi /nologo /Fa"x64/debug/" /Fd"x64/debug/vc120.pdb" /Fo"x64/debug/" /Fp"x64/debug
/%appname%.pch"  /I"%qtdir%/include" /I"%qtdir%/include/QtCore" /I"%qtdir%/include/QtGui"
 /I"%qtdir%/include/QtWidgets" "%qtdir%/lib/Qt5Guid.lib" "%qtdir%/lib/Qt5Widgetsd.lib"
 "%qtdir%/lib/Qt5Cored.lib" %src% /link /out:"x64/debug/%appname%.exe"
```

example .qrc:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="res">
    <file>res/app.ico</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Instead of `windres.exe`, the Windows SDK provides `rc.exe`, a.k.a. the Resource Compiler. You need first an image in .ico format (named here "app.ico") and a text file named "app.rc" with this content:

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "app.ico"
```

You can compile this file with this command:

```
rc app.rc
```

That command will produce a file with the name "app.res". This RES file can be processed by the linker directly, or you may convert it to .obj with this command:

```
cvtres /MACHINE:X64 app.res
```

That command produces a file with the name "app.obj" (for architecture x86_64, use `cvtres /h` to see other parameters). You need to give this .obj file to the linker when producing the executable. "cvtres.exe" comes from the VC compiler bin directory, and not the Windows SDK.